# MvcHtmlString still encoding characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-encode

I'm trying to use `MvcHtmlString.Create` to create a JavaScript variable. However the output is still being encoded.

```
var geocode_jsonresult = @MvcHtmlString.Create(Url.Action("GeoLocation", "Generic", New With {.address = "$(this).val()"}));
```

creates the following output

```
var geocode_jsonresult = /generic/GeoLocation?address=%24(this).val();
```

when really it "SHOULD" be

```
var geocode_jsonresult = /generic/GeoLocation?address=$(this).val();
```

How can I prevent this?

#### note

I'm using VB and not C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript seems broken. Shouldn't it be:

```
var geocode_jsonresult = 
    '@Url.Action("GeoLocation", "Generic")?address=' + 
        encodeUriComponent($(this).val());
```

Are trying to mix server side url helpers with client-side values?

Comment: that makes total sense, though yours doesn't quite work... this works `var geocode_jsonresult = '@Url.Action("GeoLocation", "Generic")?address=' + $(this).val()`

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'll accept in three minutes. Thanks for the direction... I should have known better.  Not sure why I was trying to add `New With` instead of just mixing it.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, also notice `encodeURIComponent`, it's important if you are building a query string because it will properly url encode it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var geocode_jsonresult = 
    '@Url.Action("GeoLocation", "Generic")?address=' + $(this).val();
```